# how i can send my asp.net project to another person through link

Tags: asp.net

Hi
I have created one asp.net application.I have to send as link to another user. How i will do that?
Asp.net c#

Thank you.

Comment: Is your goal to share your code with other developers? Or to allow other people to use your application online?

Comment: You've asked 12 questions on Stack Overflow so far, but have not accepted an answer to a single one! Revisit your previous questions and use the checkmark icon beside the answer that resolved your problem to "accept" it. You will get better answers from the community if you don't have a track record of ignoring previous answers.

Comment: yes to allow other people to use application online

Comment: So you're trying to install the application on an IIS web server, then? How far have you gotten? What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

*yes to allow other people to use application online – user707294 58 secs ago*

If you want it to work online you will need to host it on a server somewhere, and optionally buy a domain name.

Google will find you tons of results for asp.net server hosting.

Answer (score 0):

IF you want to share your app with your friends:

1. Make a zip file of your app.
2. Make a page having a download link.
3. By clicking on download link your zip will be downloaded.
4. Tell your friend to open page and click on download link.

---

Don't forget look at this link: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

---

Seen your comment that you want to run app online. Its easy buy a domain [server hosting] and put your application in it. Give others your URL. that's it others will be able to use your app online.

Answer (score 0):

Start here: http://www.asp.net/

You might go to their Hosting area to see what options are available for you.  Some are very cheap.